# Get-AzureStorageBlobContent Exception to download a blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using following command to download blob from provided container but it give me following exception.

Code

```
$subscriptionName = "mysubscrition"
$storageAccount = "myaccount"
$containerName = "mycontainer"

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName -CurrentStorageAccount $storageAccount
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Container $containerName
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $containerName | Sort LastModified -Descending |Select-Object -First 1 | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob name -Destination "C:\BlobDownload" -Force | Out-Null
```

Excetion

```
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:7 char:106
+ Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $containerName | Sort LastModified -Descending | ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureStorageBlobContent], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageBlobContentCommand
```

Comment: Which WindowsAzurePowerShell version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a transient install issue.  Can you try reinstalling as follows:

(1) uninstall
(2) Remove webpi cache directrory (~\appdata\local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer)
(3) install a fresh copy from webpi

Answer (score 0):

This is actually caused by an issue with the wix installer and the version number of the Storage.DataMovement dll. During an upgrade, the Windows Installer will not replace a file with a lower version of the same file.  What happes is that the file is marked for deletion, the replacement with the lower version file is disallowed, and then the file is removed (but not replaced).

You can solve this in two ways:

(1) Repair the install in Control Panel -> Uninstall a program

(2) Replace with a more recent version (0.8.5, for example).  The more recent versions should not display this issue