# Why Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement is removed in Azure Powershell March 2014

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

In the **Azure Powershell - February 2014** installation I see  file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.dll"
```

however when I install March 2014 version, it's gone. Why is that? I can't find anything relevant on their [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to uninstall and reinstall the binary. It should be an install/upgrade issue.

Here is the same issue [Get-AzureStorageBlobContent Exception to download a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891167/get-azurestorageblobcontent-exception-to-download-a-blob)